# Managing Roles In ASP MVC 3 Code First Approach

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am developing an ASP .Net MVC 3 application using C# and SQL Server 2005.

I am using also Entity Framework and Code First Method.

I have an interface Login that works perfectly.

My problem that I have 3 Types of Users :

- Root
- Admin
- User

and each one has a custom access to the pages of the application.

I search on the net and I found many tutos describing how to manage Roles but all are not using a database or using an existing database with ADO .NET, database first

My problem that I am using ENTITY **FRAMEWORK** and **CODE FIRST**.

[image: tables]

This is what I have in my base . How can I bind this tables with my code ? I already used `[Authorize]` in some action and its works perfectly  but now how I use `[Authorize (Roles="Admin")]` with my database.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that you are looking for in the MVC custom role provider.

You can check this:

http://kitsula.com/Article/Custom-Role-Provider-for-MVC
https://codefirstmembership.codeplex.com/
http://techbrij.com/custom-roleprovider-authorization-asp-net-mvc
http://www.mattwrock.com/post/2009/10/14/Implementing-custom-Membership-Provider-and-Role-Provider-for-Authinticating-ASPNET-MVC-Applications.aspx
http://www.danharman.net/2011/06/23/asp-net-mvc-3-custom-membership-provider-with-repository-injection/
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165159/Custom-Membership-Providers
[How to use Membership provider with EF Code First?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774706/how-to-use-membership-provider-with-ef-code-first)

Comment: THX but what I need is really how to use roles with CODE FIRST and EF

Comment: OK, therefore thought that minimum the last link one might be interested in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774706/how-to-use-membership-provider-with-ef-code-first

Comment: THx i looked this link but i am not using Membership Provider,,,i have FormsAuthentication.Login(username, password),,,self written

Comment: The simplest, fastest (and safest) way to deal with the MVC role groups, the use of (custom) membership/role provider. You can find many examples of this, be sure to take into consideration.